# Порядок выполнения операций

Tags: c, c++

Всем привет, скажите, какой будет порядок операций в `while(0 != *input++) {...}`? Cначала произойдет "0 != *input", а затем "input++"?

итак, gcc version 4.4.5

Эксперимент:

```
char * input = (char *)"R142C1543:R18999C24568";
char * tmp = input;
printf("str1 = %s\n", input);
while(0 != *input++) ;
printf("str2 = %s\n", tmp);
```

Результат:

```
str1 = R142C1543:R18999C24568
str2 = R142C1543:R18999C24568
```

Вывод: эксперемент показал, что проход данным циклом по строке не изменяет саму строку.

P.S. сейчас попытался перед первым printf'ом вставит *input = 'T' - выдало ошибку сегментирования.

```
char * input = (char *)"R142C1543:R18999C24568";
char * tmp = input;

*input = 'T'; // отладчик gdb подтвердил что ошибка сегментирования возникает на этой строчке
printf("str1 = %s\n", input);
while(0 != *input++) ;
printf("str2 = %s\n", tmp);
```

Comment: *input = 'T'; - присваивание значения константе. Строчка при таком задании находится в сегменте данных программы доступном только для чтения.

Comment: чтож, это еще раз подтверждает что цикл while(0 != *input++) ; не модифицирует строку, по которой проходимся указателем input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно таблице приоритетов операции будут выполнены в таком порядке:

1. Обращение к памяти по указателю: *input
2. Следующей будет операция сравнения: 0 != *input
3. И операция с самым низким приоритетом: постфиксный инкремент. input++, применяется непосредственно к указателю.

Использовать разыменование в комплекте с инкрементом/декрементом без скобочек надо очень осторожно. Постфиксный оператор применяется в данной ситуации (но согласно приоритету) *непосредственно* к указателю.
Но если требуется увеличить значение памяти, надо использовать соответствующую конструкцию с префиксным оператором или поставить скобочки: ++*index; (*index)++;

Порядок операций специально не оговорен, но следует из синтаксиса (The precedence of operators is not directly speciﬁed, but it can be derived from the syntax).

Comment: Удалось придумать способ проверить, вообщем да так оно и есть сначала пройдет сравнение, а потом input++

Comment: В 3 пункте наверно не "*input++", а "input++"?

Comment: Нет, именно \*input++. Сравните:<p>
(\*input)++ и \*(input++)

Comment: Угу, прибавляться будет содержимое памяти, а не указатель. Операция извлечения данных из памяти приоритетнее.

Comment: эксперементы показывают обратное - исходная строка в результате прохода по ней данным циклом остается не модифицированной.

Comment: Хм, сейчас уточню в стандарте

Comment: Так будет правильнее, видимо =)

Answer (score 2):

Итак, хотелось бы подвести итог и закрыть тем самым обсуждение, да простит меня @Алексей Сонькин, я использую его пост с небольшой поправочкой.

> Согласно таблице приоритетов операции
> будут выполнены в таком порядке:
>
> Обращение к памяти по указателю:
> *input
>
> Следующей будет операция сравнения: 0
> != *input

И операция с самым низким приоритетом: постфиксный инкремент. input++ // Та самая поправочка

> Все операции имеют чёткий порядок
> следования без каких-либо разногласий.
> Ознакомиться можно, например, по
> ссылке "Приоритеты операций"(первая
> попавшаяся ссылка).

В целом всем спасибо, было приятно пообщаться с умными людьми) Главное нашли ответ на вопрос)

Comment: Ну, тут вообще спорить не о чем. while `(*dst++ = *src++);` Это стандартное копирование строки с рождения языка C.

Answer (score 2):

Порядок исполнения операторов в операции:

```
while(0 != *input++)
```

1. Выполняется оператор ++ (постфиксный)
2. Оператор разыменование указателя * имеет **самый низкий** приоритет
3. Сравнивается результат *input++ с нулем

При этом не надо забывать, что постфисный оператор ++ увеличивает на единицу значение переменной, но возвращает **старое** значение. В результате получаем, что увеличивается раньше разыменования, но разыменование применяется для **старого** (не увеличенного) значения input. И, как следствие сравнение с нулем выполняется так же с не увеличенным значением *input.

PS: меня позабавили варианты ответов :)

Answer (score 1):

@Алексей Сонькин

> 1. Обращение к памяти по указателю: *input
> 2. Следующей будет операция сравнения: 0 != *input
> 3. И операция с самым низким приоритетом: постфиксный инкремент. input++, применяется непосредственно к указателю.

`*input++` равно `*(input++)` равно "разыменовать прежнее значение input"

операция сравнения не может быть второй, потому что у неё приоритет ниже, чем у одноместных операций (по крайней мере в C)

Answer (score 0):

**Инкремент input происходит до** операции сравнения (или по крайней мере до перехода по ее результату).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *p = "abc";

main ()
{
  char *t = p;

  while ( 0 != *t++);
  printf ("p = %d t = %d\n",p,t);
  t = p;
  while (*t++ != 0);
  printf ("p = %d t = %d\n",p,t);
}
```

Результат ее работы.

```
c:/tsttst $ gcc t.c
c:/tsttst $ ./a.exe 
p = 4206592 t = 4206596
p = 4206592 t = 4206596
c:/tsttst $
```

Как видим, после while() указатель на следующем за "abc\0" байтом.